# where is the browserLoadURL file in Firefox directory in Linux?

Tags: firefox, browser, url

I am unable to find the browserLoadURL file in Firefox directory. I want to disable file protocol.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think `browserLoadURL` is a file in Linux sense of file? What is your reference to its existence in current versions of Firefox?

If you read [this from 2009](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=7013705#p7013705), you'll see that it **was a function** (not a file):

> That particular function (BrowserLoadURL) is removed from browser.jar , so it is no longer possible the modify the BrowserLoadURL function to get that block. I had checked that at the first time of the new post (July 15) and couldn't find it, not code in other functions that looked similar. I didn't check other jar files (e.g. toolkit) to see if the code has been moved there.

I suggest you read that entire thread.

Also look at this very old bug:  [Last Comment Bug 524951 - BrowserLoadURL override broken which extensions use limit file:/// access](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=524951) .